# Short black screen after login

Tags: login, xorg, display-resolution

When I login in to Ubuntu my monitor goes black, almost as If it switching resolution, and then when it comes back on the desktop appears. How do I get it so that the monitor stays on during the login process? When I had Ubuntu installed on laptop there was an animation when going from login screen to desktop.

I am using a 144hz monitor, Nvidia GPU with Xorg and proprietary drivers

What I have tried:

- I have managed to get the login screen to be the same resolution as my user session (1920x1080 144hz) by putting the monitor.xml file in the gdm3 folder. This made the login screen 144hz but the problems still persists
- Copying the xorg.conf file into /etc/x11/. This doesn't change the resolution of the login screen, however, combined with the monitor.xml fix above, the tail end of the login animation is visable for some reason.

I honestly have no idea what is happening, feel free to ask for more information about my setup if necessary. Any help is appreciated.

GRUB log as asked in comments.

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Comment: Please open a terminal and type `sudo cat /etc/default/grub` and then copy & paste the half-a-dozen lines at the top that start with **GRUB_** by editing your question above and adding those lines so we can read.

Comment: I don't want to change the grub menu. How would this help?

Comment: You might see some goings on that provide more information. Edit your grub so that you get the grub menu at boot. Change **hidden** to read **menu** and then change the timeout from **0** to **10** then commit the change and don't forget to `sudo update-grub` before you reboot. So now you boot to the grub menu and if you wait 10 it will just carry on as normal however if you press `e` you can temorarily edit your GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="rhgb nosplash acpi_enforce_resources=lax pcie_ports=compat" and see what you get.